# javascript add rel facebox

Tags: javascript

i want to enable facebox jquery using javascript.

here in normal html

```
<a href="stairs.jpg" rel="facebox">text</a>
```

how do in javascript ?something like this?

```
document.location.href="stairs.jpg";
document.location.rel="facebox";
```

Comment: huh ? please try to explain a bit what you are trying to do ...

Comment: do you need help enabling facebox on your page or adding links that will use facebox?

Comment: Jeez, don't flag an answer when you want to make a comment on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to open a facebox window and populate it with stairs.jpg then you would use the following:

```
jQuery.facebox({ image: 'stairs.jpg' });
```

Answer (score 0):

Is something like this, what you are looking for ?

```
var alink = document.createElement('a');
alink.setAttribute('href', 'stairs.jpg');
alink.setAttribute('rel','facebox');
```

Comment: OP flagged your answer, "hey i tried what u hv suggested when i needed to do the same thing. it dsnt work like a normal wud wrk. m still lukin for the solution".